# How to display graph for three nodes where first node is connected to third via second node using ne04j cypher?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, analytics

I am trying to figure out insights where `(node1)-[:related_to]->(node2)-[:belongs_to]->(node3)`. I want to display like  `(node1)-[:belongs_to]->(node3)` based on above relationship. Three relationship was created.

```
MATCH (n2:node2),(n3:node3)
WHERE n2.Name = n3.Name
CREATE (n3) <- [:BELONGS_TO]- (n2)

MATCH (n1:node2),(n2:node2)
CREATE (n1) <- [:related_to]- (n2)

MATCH (n1:node2),(n2:node2)
CREATE (n2) <- [:related_to]- (n1)
```

I have tried this query but it's giving me via relationship.

```
MATCH (n1:node1)-[r1:related_to]-(n2:node2)-[r2:BELONGS_TO]-(n3:node3) 
RETURN n1,n2,n3
```

I am new in this field and trying to bring few insights. Your valuable feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `(n)-->(m)-->(p)`, the relationship `(n)-->(p)` doesn't exist in the database.

So to do what you want, you will need *APOC*. There are some procedures/functions to create virtual graph.

```
MATCH (n1:node1)-[r1:related_to]-(n2:node2)-[r2:BELONGS_TO]-(n3:node3) 
WITH n1, n3
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(n1,'belongs_to',{​}, n3) YIELD rel
RETURN n1,n3, rel
```

Example : https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/virtual/